# When running shiny app, one function returns: default method not implemented for type 'list'

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I am learning how to build shiny apps. 
One function for my app does not work and says that default method not implemented for type 'list'

So, what I do:
In my app, firstly, a user chooses the products that she has in the fridge and then my model recommends the recipe and also lists products that she needs to buy to cook the dish.
I try to store results from the mentioned function to data.frame and then to a vector, so the next function will recommend where to take products for free.

```
need_prod <- reactive({ 
    input$submit
    if (input$submit == 0){
      return()
    }

    prodprod <- (as.data.frame(recipe_recommendation(isolate(input$product),
                                                     isolate(input$recipe))))$need
    prodprod <- as.character(unlist(sapply(prodprod, function(x) strsplit(x, ", ")[[1]])))
})
```

Then I want the function to take the values in need_prod and build a recommendation based on it:

```
output$table2 <- renderTable({
    input$submit
    if (input$submit == 0){
      return()
    }

    my.data <- need_prod()
    print(my.data)
    vk_connector(my.data)[1,] #vk_connector is a function. it works with vectors
}, outputArgs = data.frame())
```

The function `zk_connector` throws the following error:

```
default method not implemented for type 'list'
```

but it works fine when I run this function with simple vector.

Comment: Are you sure that `my.data` is a vector as expected? It might be worth adding `class(my.data)` to your `renderTable` and letting us know what they say.

Comment: it says "character". but when I run "print(is.finite(my.data))" it returns:  Error in is.finite: default method not implemented for type 'list'